# How to grab a specific column based off of a function input

Tags: r

I have a function that takes as input a specific column name. I then want to grab the column of a data frame that corresponds to that name. The problem is if I have code like this:

`New <- function(name) {
    dataframe$name
   }`

then it looks for the column with the name "name" and not the name I input in the function. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Use: `New <- function(name) { dataframe[, name] }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tyler mentioned in a comment

```
New <- function(name) { dataframe[, name] }
```

or, alternatively,

```
New <- function(name) { dataframe[[name]] }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add my 5c. Two alternatives above behave differently when the column with the given name does not exist. This may be important for what you do.

```
dataframe[, name]
```

will return an error, while

```
dataframe[[name]]
```

will return NULL